# Getting the result of an excel formula in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I need to open a .xlsx-file (without writing to it) in python, to change some fields and get the output after the formulas in some fields were calculated; I only know the input fields, the output field and the name of the sheet.

To write some code: Here is how it would look like if I would have created the library

```py
file = excel.open("some_file.xlsx")
sheet = file[sheet_name]
for k, v in input_fields.items():
    sheet[k] = v
file.do_calculations()
print(sheet[output_field])
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Wich library should I use to get the result of the formulas after providing new values for some fields?

Is there a better way than using something like pyoo, maybe something that doesn't require another application (a python library is clearly better) to be installed?

I'll just thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I now came up with a (very ugly) solution.

I am now reading the xml within the xlsx-file, and I am now using `eval` and some regular expressions to find out wich fields are needed; and I have defined some functions to run the calculations.

It works, but it would be great if there were a better solution.

If the resulting library is ready, and I don't forget to do this; I'll add a link to the library (that'll be hosted on Github) to this answer to my own question.